# Equivalent of NumPy's binary indexing in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following operations that depend on `Numpy`

```
trimap1[trimap1 <= 85] = 0
trimap1[trimap1 >= 170] = 255
trimap1[np.logical_and(trimap1 > 85, trimap1 < 170)] = 127
```

Right now I hope to do it in Tensorflow. Is there any equivalent expressions to them?

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't do binary indexing, unfortunately. You can wrap a python function with tf.function or convert the tensor to numpy. I suggest wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where?hl=en):

```
# coding: utf-8
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(0)
# random matrix
a = tf.random.uniform((3, 3), 0, 255, tf.int32)
trimap = tf.where(a <= 85, tf.zeros_like(a), a)
trimap = tf.where(a >= 170, 255 * tf.ones_like(a), trimap)
trimap = tf.where(tf.logical_and(a > 85, a < 170), 127 * tf.ones_like(a), trimap)
```

Inspecting `a` and `trimap`:

```
>>> a
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 78,  14,  36],
       [ 17,  12,  59],
       [240, 134,  51]], dtype=int32)> 
>>> trimap
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [255, 127,   0]], dtype=int32)>
```